# Correct use of Generics

Tags: java, generics, primefaces

From primefaces I have..

```
public abstract class LazyDataModel<T> extends DataModel<T> implements SelectableDataModel<T>, Serializable {
```

------------EDIT-------------

Full class from primefaces

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009-2012 Prime Teknoloji.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.primefaces.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.model.DataModel;

/**
 * Custom lazy loading DataModel to deal with huge datasets
 */
public abstract class LazyDataModel<T> extends DataModel<T> implements SelectableDataModel<T>, Serializable {

    private int rowIndex = -1;

    private int rowCount;

    private int pageSize;

    private List<T> data;

    public LazyDataModel() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        if(data == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < data.size();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }

    public T getRowData() {
        return data.get(rowIndex);
    }

    public int getRowIndex() {
        return this.rowIndex;
    }

    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
    }

    public Object getWrappedData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setWrappedData(Object list) {
        this.data = (List) list;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }
    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }

    public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
    }

    public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String,String> filters) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
    }

    public T getRowData(String rowKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.");
    }

    public Object getRowKey(T object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getRowKey(T object) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.");
    }
}
```

-------------END EDIT---------------------

I have created

```
public class LazyRetiDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<Rete> {

    public void setFilters( Map<String, String> filters ) {
        this.qbeFilters = filters;
    }
}
```

I must use lazy model as

```
 private LazyDataModel<Rete> lazyModel;
 lazyModel = new LazyRetiDataModel<>( cfgRetePstnTAB );
```

In my code I have

```
Map<String, String> mappa = ABAcus.createMap( p1,p2, p3, p4, p5);

if (lazyModel != null) {
            ((LazyRetiDataModel) lazyModel).setFilters( mappa );
}
```

I obtain this warning

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setFilters(Map<String,String>) as a member of the raw type LazyRetiDataModel
                ((LazyRetiDataModel) lazyModel).setFilters( mappa );
```

Right because `LazyRetiDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<Rete>`  so I solved with   `((LazyRetiDataModel<?>) lazyModel).setFilters( mappa );`

but `?` is correct.?

---

SOLVED the correct answer is

The suggestion made by Tom Hawtin, Mark Peters also with his words changed my vision.
I defined

```
private LazyRetiDataModel lazyModel;
```

Anyway  Luiggi Mendoza and Paul Bellora gave me an important idea about Generics and i think that the correct definition of class is

```
public class LazyRetiDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Rete> {
```

LazyRetiDataModel does not use the generics.

Comment: It's much better not to cast at all. Just change the type of `lazyModel`.

Comment: IMO it should be `LazyRetiDataModel<Rete> extends LazyDataModel<Rete>` or `LazyRetiDataModel<T extends Rete> extends LazyDataModel<Rete>`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok i try your suggestion is correct in the original example I found that kind of extends.
I think that the main motivatio is the use of '@Override'
    public List<Rete> load( int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters ) {

Comment: Agree with Tom.  If you're going to blindly assume that `lazyModel` is a `LazyRetiDataModel`, then just declare it as such and gain static type safety.

Comment: @MarkPeters,@TomHawtin-tackline using primefaces i need to return the lezy model as  
`public LazyDataModel<Rete> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;
    }`
In PrimeFace there is a call to getLazyModel, it wait a LazyDataModel<T> and show a table of objects T where T is Rete

Comment: @MarkPeters,@TomHawtin-tackline I reverse the problem cast to supertipe is free so i follow this idea I change the type of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion made by Tom Hawtin, Mark Peters also with his words changed my vision. I defined

private LazyRetiDataModel lazyModel;
Anyway Luiggi Mendoza and Paul Bellora gave me an important idea about Generics and i think that the correct definition of class is

public class LazyRetiDataModel extends LazyDataModel {
LazyRetiDataModel does not use the generics.

java generics primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Why is `public class LazyRetiDataModel<T>` generic in the first place? It defines the generic parameter for the superclass and if that is the only method it has (setFilters), then just simply remove the .
UPDATE:
If there are no generic methods using the newly defined , then it should be removed. As you mentioned it overrides some methods, which cannot use the new  (if I'm correct), so I still think you might not need the new .

Comment: In its current form, this looks like a comment. Please update it to look like a real constructive answer.

Comment: No it has to ovveride methods of Lazy data model

Comment: Ok, now I read the full super-class. You really don't have to make LazyRetiDataModel generic.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a warning because you're casting to the raw type `LazyRetiDataModel`. I would recommend the following instead:

```
if (lazyModel != null) {
    ((LazyRetiDataModel<Rete>)lazyModel).setFilters(mappa);
}
```

Typically, this would result in an unchecked cast warning, but this is actually an exception to that rule since the compiler already knows the generic type is `Rete`.

Note that I also agree with Luiggi Mendoza's comment about `LazyRetiDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<Rete>` probably being a typo - you want `LazyRetiDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<T>`.

Comment: As I told in comment @LuiggiMendoza the use of <Rete> in LazyDataModel is mandatory the class uses the generic everywhere example `public List<T> load(`